# How to add convert column chart to stackcolumn chart in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, asp.net-charts

I have a column chart and it is working fine with the following code. Now I want to make it a stack column chart by adding Crickettime, Hockeytime, with the existing football time. I have similar procedures to find Crickettime and Hockeytime. I think I need to specify series in the following method so that series1 is football time, and series2 is Cricket time, and series 3 is hockey time. Any help on how to specify the series.

```
private void GetChartData2(){
    SqlConnection con2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        con2.ConnectionString = "connectionstring";

        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Execute spGetFootballTimeOftheUsersPerDay_Updated '" + currentUser + "'", con2);
        cmd2.CommandTimeout = 0;

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter sqldataadap2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
        sqldataadap2.SelectCommand = cmd2;

        DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
        dtable.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        sqldataadap2.Fill(dtable);
        Chart2.DataSource = dtable;


        Chart2.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: Are you working on Webforms or MVC?

Comment: I am using asp.net c#

Answer (score 0):

I have face this type of prbolem. I get the solution.

**Following Step below.**

you can manage your data using only one series with all column(Football,Hocky,Cricket)

**Stacked chart work series 1 means all column data display same time**

**you go through manage data column wise like you get 
First point cricket column data than add another column data is 0
your table first row(cricket) get 100 than add balnk another row for football and hocky**

below type of table

No   Game       Score

1   Cricket     100
2   hocky       0
3   Football    0

4   Cricket     0
5   hocky       200
6   Football    0

7   Cricket     0
8   hocky       0
9   Football    300

Example - cricket data(0)= 100 Football(0)= 0  Hocky(0) = 0

Series.Points(0) X=0,Y=100 Cricket
                                  (1) X=0,Y=0   Football
                                  (2) X=0,Y=0   Hocky

you have to mange this type of data.

Series Data
Cricket data 1 to 100 than generate SRno 1 to 100
Hocky data 1 to 100 than generate SRno 1 to 100
Football data 1 to 100 than generate srno 1 to 100

Below code

```
BreakWisechart.DataBindCrossTable(dv, "SrNo", "GameColumn", "Score","Tooltip=GameColumn,Label=Score")

For Each cs As Series In BreakWisechart.Series
    With cs
        .ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn

        For Each Points In cs.Points
            **If Points.ToolTip = "1" Then
                .Color = Color.Red
            Else
                .Color = Color.Green
            End If**
        Next
        .IsValueShownAsLabel = False
        .YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary
        .Font = New Font("Calibri", 6, FontStyle.Regular)
    End With
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try it when I get time.